# how to access react inline styling from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am repurposing an array of react components and I want to change the inline styles that they get generated with. How do I, for instance, console.log the inline styles of a react component?

EDIT: code snippet below:

```js
const pieces = this.props.pieces.map((decl, i) => {
  const isMoving = draggingPiece && i === draggingPiece.index;
  const { x, y, piece } = decode.fromPieceDecl(decl);
  const Piece = pieceComponents[piece];

  return (
    <Draggable
      bounds="parent"
      position={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
      onStart={this.handleDragStart}
      onDrag={this.handleDrag}
      onStop={this.handleDragStop}
      key={`${piece}-${x}-${y}`}
      >
      <Piece isMoving={isMoving} x={x} y={y} />
    </Draggable>
  );
});

console.log(pieces[8].style) // error
```

Comment: Can you post a small sample of one the components you want to print the style from?

Comment: @alex it's in..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. At least not from the outside of that component.

In your code here `pieces[8]` is a function that renders JSX, and not the result of a render. So any inline styles would not have been rendered yet.

You best bet would be to go into the code of the `Piece` component, and `console.log` out the variables that create those inline styles.

Comment: The 'draggable' component is the one I want to change the styles on and the source code is ridiculously complicated native react. It's a module I've imported which works great except there's a small bug where a single Draggable component keeps it's transform property after certain movements.

Is there not a way to change the inline styles later?